# nginx javascript module persistence

Tags: javascript, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config, njs

Is it possible to persist some data in the javascript module of nginx?

I need to safe some data from the request to validate if the following requests are allowed.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try to use it by writing a file and reading it.
https://github.com/nginx/njs/issues/75 Here is someone kinda using it.
Second idea would be to just try to setup it as a nginx variable or something.
https://www.docs4dev.com/docs/en/nginx/current/reference/http-ngx_http_js_module.html

Comment: Files are to slow, and i cant use nginx variables in javascript :/

Comment: per-request parsing on the shared source (file) is far from the data sharing... NJS variables are per-request entities, thus they could NOT be shared between requests

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to use [ngx_http_keyval_module](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_keyval_module.html). it allows to keep key-value dictionaries in the shared memory available to all requests and workers.

Take a look at the [number of requests per client IP](https://github.com/nginx/njs-examples/#logging-the-number-of-requests-per-client-http-logging-num-requests) example.

**nginx.conf**

```
...

http {
  js_path "/etc/nginx/njs/";

  js_import num_requests_module from logging/num_requests_module.js;
  js_set $num_requests num_requests_module.num_requests;

  keyval_zone zone=foo:10m;    
  keyval $remote_addr $foo zone=foo;

  log_format bar '$remote_addr [$time_local] $num_requests';

  access_log logs/access.log bar;

  server {
        listen 80;

        location / {
            return 200;
        }
  }
}
```

**num_requests_module.js:**

```
function num_requests(r) {
    var n = r.variables.foo; // read variable from the share memory
    n = n ? Number(n) + 1 : 1;
    r.variables.foo = n; // persist variable in the shared memory
    return n;
}

export default {num_requests};
```

**Checking:**

```
curl http://localhost/aa; curl http://localhost/aa; curl http://localhost/aa
curl --interface 127.0.0.2 http://localhost/aa; curl --interface 127.0.0.2 http://localhost/aa

docker logs njs_example
127.0.0.1 [22/Nov/2021:16:55:06 +0000] 1
127.0.0.1 [22/Nov/2021:16:55:07 +0000] 2
127.0.0.1 [22/Nov/2021:16:55:29 +0000] 3
127.0.0.2 [22/Nov/2021:18:20:24 +0000] 1
127.0.0.2 [22/Nov/2021:18:20:25 +0000] 2
```